# C# How to separate string with out separator?

Tags: c#, string

how to separate something from `83726473827` to

```
int[0] = 8;
int[1] = 3;
int[2] = 7;
```

etc...

I don't want use any separator

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833391/convert-chars-corresponding-to-digits-to-uint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq extension method `Select` with `char.getNumericValue()` like this:

```
using System.Linq;

string str = "83726473827";

int[] array = str.Select(c => (int)char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray();

foreach ( int value in array )
  Console.WriteLine(value);
```

We take each char of the string and convert them to numeric value as integer, then we take the result as an array.

This code assumes that the string contains only digits else we need to take in consideration other cases.

*Output*

```
8
3
7
2
6
4
7
3
8
2
7
```